# Problem with changing user to root

Tags: linux, root, users

I tried to make my account root by editing etc/group:

```
root:x:0:oneat
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:oneat
...
```

But it didn't succeed.
What can I do more?

Comment: There is only one `root`, and his UID is zero. The rest are normal users. The `adm` group does pretty much nothing in most Linux distros. Even the `root` group gives no access.

Comment: Living in an account with root privs on all the time is a terrible idea. You will accidentally destroy your system by running a poorly-written app or issuing a slightly wrong shell command, if malware doesn't get you first. Back when personal computer OSes didn't have separate accounts, so you were effectively root all the time, there were safeguards so that even as root, you couldn't shoot yourself in the foot too easily. Those safeguards don't exist anymore, because you're not expected to run as root all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to do, the correct way to perform tasks as root is to use `sudo` or to use `su` or login as root.

Comment: My account is configured with lots of private data and it would be iritating moving everything to root. So I want just to set it to root because using everywhere sudo isn't comfortable and it's only my home PC.

Comment: @oneat Moving _what_ to root? You won't lose access to your own files. /// "it's only my home PC" must've been exactly what the Windows XP guys said when making all users Administrators by default.

Comment: You can use `sudo -s` to get a root shell so you don't have to keep typing `sudo`.

Comment: I mean favorites and places.

Comment: @oneat: If you need to run GUI apps as root, use `gksudo`.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to have done is add your user to the `adm` and `root` groups. This, by itself, does not make your account root.

There are two common ways of being an administrator on unix systems:
* either know the password for the `root` user, and call `su` to run commands as root;
* or be registered as a *sudoer*, and call `sudo` to run commands as root.

The way to register as a sudoer is to be listed in the `sudoers` file (which you can edit by running `visudo` as root — never update this file manually or demons will eat your children's souls). Sudo can be set up so that all members of a certain group are sudoers; for example, on Ubuntu, all members of the `admin` group are sudoers.

If you already had the permission to run `sudo`, the changes you've made won't do anything useful. I recommend you carefully undo them: it's always a bad idea to mess up with security settings you don't understand.

Prefixing commands to run as root with `su` or `sudo` is the normal way to do things under unix. If you feel you have to do it too often, it probably means you've tackled some problem the wrong way. Unless you administer a multi-user machine or multi-usage server, few common tasks require explicitly running commands as root.

Answer (score 1):

The group `root` (`gid=0`) has practically no meaning.

You could create a new user that shares the same `uid=0` with `root`, and you could even give it a different password and shell and homedir, too.  Some tools don't cope well with a many-to-one user-to-uid mapping, though.

Historically, members of the group `wheel` are allowed to `su` to root, and most distributions are set up to allow members of `wheel` and/or `adm` to `sudo`.  This is a much better mechanism than attempting to bestow your account with permanent `uid=0` powers.

Editing `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group`, `/etc/gshadow`, etc. by hand is an easy way to break your system.

Comment: I'm allowed too. But I prefer graphical interface instead Command line.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. You *will* inevitably screw up your system completely running as root all the time.

What task do you find yourself performing so often that you must become root to handle it?

Comment: I'm testing tools, configuring my system etc. I just don't like to lunch everything from command line instead clicking it. And I also want to have my pulpit and everything under my hand.